# Select com max(data), penultima(data)

Tags: sql-select, mysql, order-by

Tenho uma tabela com código do produto e data da venda.
Gostaria de fazer um select pegando o código do produto, a data da última venda e a data da penúltima venda com group by código. É possível?

```
select 

p.codigo,
max(date_format(p.data_venda, '%d/%m/%Y')) Data_Ultima_Venda,
(max(date_format(p.data_venda, '%d/%m/%Y'))-interval 1 day) Data_Penultima_Venda

from 
    itens i

inner join pedidos p on p.id=i.pedido_id

group by p.codigo
order by p.data_venda DESC
limit 10;
```

Comment: Você precisa dar mais informações sobre sua consulta, poste o código que você estava elaborando para que seja possível lhe guiar para a resposta correta.

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba: select 

p.codigo,
max(date_format(p.data_venda, '%d/%m/%Y')) Data_Ultima_Venda,
(max(date_format(p.data_venda, '%d/%m/%Y'))-interval 1 day) Data_Penultima_Venda

from 
 itens i

inner join pedidos p on p.id=i.pedido_id

group by p.codigo
order by p.data_venda DESC
limit 10;

Comment: [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/177227/edit) sua pergunta e adicione o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não consegui testar 100% aqui mas acredito que seja isto que esteja procurando...

O que eu fiz, eu fiz um select igual o seu, porem peguei o `max data_venda` que não é igual ao primeiro obviamente sendo o penultimo

```
 select
     p.id, 
     max(p.data_venda) Data_Ultima_Venda, 
     (select 
        max(p2.data_venda) 
        from pedidos p2
        where p2.id= p.id
        and p2.data_venda <> max(p.data_venda)      
        group by p2.id
     ) Data_Penultima_Venda 
 from itens i 
    inner join pedidos p on p.id=i.pedido_id 
 group by p.id
order by p.data_venda DESC
limit 10;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!